# Access socket ref to pass to child process

Tags: node.js, sockets, ipc, child-process, file-descriptor

Using Node.js, I can pass a handle/ref for a http request to a child process using this construct:

```
const k = cp.fork(childPath);

const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
  k.send('foo', req.socket);
});
```

and in the child process, I can do:

```
process.on('message', (m, socket) => {
    // 'foo', socket
    socket.write([
      'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
      'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
      'Content-Encoding: UTF-8',
      'Accept-Ranges: bytes',
      'Connection: keep-alive',
    ].join('\n') + '\n\n');
  
    socket.write(`
    <h1> Example </h1>
  `);
    
    socket.end('foobar');
};
```

which is pretty cool, allows child processes to write directly to requests.

I am wondering, how I can do the same for a websocket server:

```
const ws = require('ws');
const server = new ws.WebSocketServer({port: 5151});
```

I assume passing a connection to a child process should work:

```
server.on('connection', c => {
   k.send('foo', c);  /// error here
});
```

but I get an **error**, saying:

`This handle type cannot be sent`

not sure if websocket connections have sockets as do http connections?

Comment: websocket connections are just a TCP connection underneath their protocol parsing layer.  In fact, they start life as an http connection and that very TCP socket of the http connection is then converted to the webSocket protocol by passing it to a webSocket protocol layer.  The lack of being able to pass a webSocket is not because you can't pass the TCP socket, it's because nobody has written the code to hook up a new webSocket wrapper in the child process around the TCP socket that gets passed.  Probably just hasn't been a serious priority to write that code.

Comment: @jfriend00 perhaps so, see my answer though

Comment: I do wonder, more importantly, if the socket ref can be passed more directly to the child process instead of being sent as an IPC message

Comment: What is "more direct" than an IPC message?  These are separate processes so you have to use some interprocess communication, right?  And there's a Javascript object wrapped around the underlying TCP system socket and you can't directly  pass that Javascript object as it belongs to a given interpreter's VM so you have to pass the system socket and then rewrap it in a new Javascript object in the new VM.  Plus with webSocket, there is state in the Javascript wrapper that must also be transferred.

Comment: I mean you could pass the file descriptor from parent to child via the shell as env var or process.argv, not sure if that captures all information tho

Comment: coincidentally I have an old question about this -https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1312

Comment: For something like a command line arg or an env var, you're assuming the file descriptor is as simple as something like a number that can be put in a string.  I don't think that's the case on all platforms.  Besides, it has ownership issues and privilege issues and stuff like that and then it has to be wrapped in the appropriate Javascript object so you can use it from a different JS VM.  `process.send()` does all this work for you for a plain socket in a cross platform way. It just hasn't implemented it for a webSocket that needs additional state passed and another layer above the TCP socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This handle type cannot be sent

websocket connections are just a TCP connection underneath their protocol parsing layer. In fact, they start life as an http connection and that very TCP socket of the http connection is then converted to the webSocket protocol by passing it to a webSocket protocol layer.

The lack of being able to pass a webSocket to a child process is not because you can't pass the TCP socket, it's because nobody has written the code to hook up a new webSocket wrapper in the child process around the TCP socket that gets passed. Probably just hasn't been a serious priority to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's accessible via an underscored property:

```
server.on('connection', c => {

    console.log('new connection');

    const k = cp.fork('k.js', [],{
        stdio: 'pipe',
        detached: false
    });


    k.send({handle:true}, c._socket); // <--- here

});
```

Comment: Won't this just pass the underlying TCP socket, but then once in the child process, it won't be treated as a webSocket and thus won't do proper webSocket protocol?

Comment: yeah idk, it works with http, but with websockets, I am getting this error: https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/2098

Comment: Yeah, http just has a plain TCP socket that you can `.write()` http syntax to.  webSocket has a different protocol that includes encryption and data frames and all that.  You need a webSocket layer on top of the TCP socket with the encryption state from the original webSocket in order to use the underlying TCP socket as a webSocket.

Comment: That error you're getting sounds like you're trying to just write plain data to a webSocket, but you can't do that.  You have to write webSocket protocol in proper webSocket data frames using the proper encryption.  In other words, you need a webSocket client in the receiving process that takes over the state from the original webSocket and adopts the raw socket after it has been transferred to the child.  Not as simple to do as it is for http.

Comment: FYI, you can see some description of a webSocket data frame here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#exchanging_data_frames.  That's what has to be written to the socket.  You can even see the bits labeled RSV2 and RSV3 that your error message is referring to (that it has detected are incorrect).